# How do I apply a GTK+2 theme file?

Tags: themes

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. How do I install and apply: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Teds+Grey+TRON+Scheme?content=150416

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Or actually is more likely that you break your current theme if you try to. It was thinked for being used in GNOME 2 (as can be seen in the above screenshots). I would recommend you to check [GTK 3.x themes](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/135/order/latest/) instead. Also, you must use themes that has an instruction, in this case the theme was supposed to go in the `~/.theme` directory.

[image]